# Undefined reference to global variable

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I'm working with C, and the Quake 3 / ioquake engine. Note that this is not a game engine specific question, it's purely a C language query.

`g_entities` is a variable defined globally in the engine. There is also use of an `extern` statement for this variable.

Numerous other `.c` files within the engine call this variable without problem, however when I do this from my code, I get an `undefined reference to g_entities` linker error on compile.

**My code:**

```
// get entity information for this bot (e.g. health etc)
gentity_t *entity;
entity = &g_entities[1];
```

**Error on make:**

```
/home/george/Desktop/ioquake/ioquake-latest/ioquake3/code/botlib/be_ai_char.c:1196: undefined reference to `g_entities'
```

I would appreciate any advice any C guru could spare that might point me to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: You might be missing an include file for where that variable is actually declared.

Comment: @Danny, that was my initial suspicion. I'm including the file that it's declared in, and I get the error above. When I omit the include, I get a different error - `g_entities is undeclared`

Comment: Are you by any chance using C++ rather than a C? If yes, that could be the reason and you'd need to declare the variable `extern "C"`.

Comment: @NikosC. forgive me if I'm ignorant/wrong with this, but I'm using `make` which I believe is using `gcc`.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a header file issue. You need to link against an object that contains the definition of g_entities. This could be an object file or a library. Sometimes the order in which you link things also makes a difference.

Do you know where g_entities is defined? The other code references this symbol, how doe it resolve it? What does it link against?

Comment: I've considered this and looked in to it. It's *defined* in g_main.c, which is the "main" C file for the entire engine. Obviously, all other code files are included from *that* file onwards. The only thing I can think of is the ordering of `#include`s, and I've tried several, but to no avail.

Comment: Paste the output of "nm -A g_main.o | grep -i g_entities". Also paste the link line from the build output (make output).

Comment: Thanks for your input Ziffusion. Please see the following: http://pastie.org/private/ozggrbg5mjkktx93vo6aeg

Comment: Can you paste more of the build output? I don't see the link line. Maybe just paste the entire build output. Also, paste the portion of the g_local.h where the reference to g_entities is being declared.

Comment: I don't see g_main.o in there anywhere. Can you make sure that it is being linked? Seems to me some of the details of the build output are being suppressed. Check to see if there is a way to make it produce verbose output. Paste that. But first make sure that g_main.o is being linked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28627/discussion-between-ziffusion-and-george)

Answer (score 1):

Is it because the module which actually defines g_entities (without the extern) is missing in the set of inputs to the linker (and most likely all other modules which reference it)?

Comment: The variable is actually *defined* in g_main.c, which I believe is the main "entry point" for the entire Quake 3 engine.